# Troubles installing MPLABX on Trusty

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 64-bit

I'm trying to install MPLABX on my brand new ubuntu 14.04 and i found there are lots of problems. I already did it on 13.10 64bits with no major troubles

In the microchip site says i need to instal a few dependences but not for most 64-bits linux OS. Since i couldn't make the installer work i did it anyway, it didn't work and i found that ia32-lib is no longer supported (needed) on ubuntu

[Microchip's linux-64 dependences site](http://microchip.wikidot.com/install%3amplabx-lin64)

I tried to install ia32-libs replacements (lib32z1, lib32ncurses5 and lib32bz2-1.0) but that didn't work either

The installer is a .run. I give it permission to execute and run it with sudo but it fails and gives no error message at all

If anyone could help me please! I really need to make it work

Answer (score 1):

use the installation instructions of CCS 6 TI IDE.
those instructions work also for the 14.04LTS

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Linux_Host_Support_CCSv6

that says the following:

ok here they are:

Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Resolve Dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libx11-6:i386 libasound2:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libice6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libsm6:i386 liborbit2:i386 libudev1:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libgnomeui-0:i386 libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

and after that it contiues with things for the CCS6 TI IDE

Comment: Welcome to ask-ubuntu and thank you for your answer. Although it is always good to cite one's sources it would be good if you could post the relevant parts here. So that they are still available should the source site be inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble, and could install MPLABX with the next code:
sudo ./MPLABX-v2.10-linux-installer.run --mode text

Good luck!

Yamil